# System.NullReferenceException: while writing to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am creating a signup page and the file used to store the user details via regiration form is XML file. When I am writing the entries using the code below the system is throwing an exception of NullReferenceException.

```
 protected void register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //var path = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data\\PageData.xml");
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/userlogs.xml"));
        XElement user = new XElement("user",
            new XElement("fname", fname.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("lname", lname.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("dob", dob.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("uid", uid.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("pwd", pwd.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("email", email.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("lastlog", System.DateTime.Now.ToString())
            );
        doc.Root.Element("users").Add(user);
        doc.Save("userlog.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        error.Visible = true;
        error.Text = exe.ToString();
    }
}
```

My userslog.xml File format:-

```
<users>
    <user>
        <fname>abc</fname>
        <lname>xyz</lname>
        <dob>MM/DD/YYYY</dob>
        <uid>username</uid>
        <pwd>***</pwd>
        <email>pqrs@xyz.com</email>
        <lastlog>DATE:TIME</lastlog>
    </user>
</users>
```

By this code i want to create new  tag

```
<users>
    <user>
        <fname>abc</fname>
        <lname>xyz</lname>
        <dob>MM/DD/YYYY</dob>
        <uid>username</uid>
        <pwd>***</pwd>
        <email>pqrs@xyz.com</email>
        <lastlog>DATE:TIME</lastlog>
    </user>
    <user>
        <fname>bcd</fname>
        <lname>lmo</lname>
        <dob>MM/DD/YYYY</dob>
        <uid>username1</uid>
        <pwd>***</pwd>
        <email>pqrs@xyz.com</email>
        <lastlog>DATE:TIME</lastlog>
    </user>
</users>
```

So it want my code to make my file run in the following desired manner.

[image: I am getting the following error on debugging]

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out . . .

Comment: There shouldn't be any attempt to figure out. You just do it. When your program throws the error, the IDE will clearly indicate which line it is (execute your program in debug mode).

Comment: error is coming on Line 31

Comment: which line is 31  here?

Comment: @Reeyash: And line 31 is...????

Comment: my humble apologies. . . doc.Root.Element("users").Add(user);

Answer (score 1):

from the code given there can be one possibility for getting `NullReferenceException`

1.Please check wether your xml file is available or not in following path:

```
~/App_Data/userlogs.xml
```

--> your file should be placed in `RootFolder of Project/App_Data/`

before proceeding further you can Check wether file exists or not by:

```
System.IO.File.Exists(filepath)
{
//true so file exists
//contine
}
```

Comment: My file is in the RootFolder of the project and it does exist. I checked the same by deleting the file the system. It is throwing File not found exception.

Comment: sorry i did not get you, your files is in the RootFolder?

Comment: yes . my userslog.xml lies in App_Data directory. and it is correctly linked in the program and normally accessed.

Comment: no it is not. .i have added a snapshot in my question of the errors that i am getting. can you check the pic and tell me.

Comment: try adding like this => doc.Root.Add(user);

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the program.

Remove the try catch part, so that the program will flow the exception

Add a breakpoint to see how the program runs

Try these:

- does the file `App_Data/userlogs.xml` exists?
- is the "doc" object null?

Post more code if possible

Comment: the file exists. . . . 

The NullReferenceException is coming on -doc.Root.Element("users").Add(User);

Comment: Then did you check whether the "doc" is null or the "User" is null?

Comment: or the "doc.Root.Element("user") is null?

Comment: my root node is <users>. and user is not null

Comment: Try typing "doc.Root.Element("users")" in the immediate window and see what's the output

Answer (score 0):

This is the final working code: thanks to @sudhakar

```
protected void register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //var path = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data\\PageData.xml");
    File.Exists("~/App_Data/userlogs.xml");
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/userlogs.xml"));
        XElement user = new XElement("user",
            new XElement("fname", fname.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("lname", lname.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("dob", dob.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("uid", uid.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("pwd", pwd.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("email", email.Text.ToString()),
            new XElement("lastlog", System.DateTime.Now.ToString())
            );
        doc.Root.Add(user);
        doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/userlogs.xml"));
    }
}
```